# React Native : BUILD FAILED after doing "yarn ios"

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, ios-simulator, yarnpkg-v2

I cloned a React Native app from github and followed the instructions in the Readme file (`yarn install`; `cd ios && pod install`). The app was built successfully in Xcode, but when i try to run it from my terminal using `yarn ios` the build failed.

The error is not descriptive enough, i can't figure out what caused the problem!!

#### Here is the error I am getting

[image]

If anyone has experienced such a thing before, please help me.

Comment: Hello! What's the version from XCode, React-Native and MacOS that you are using?

Comment: React-Native : `"0.65.1"` ; Xcode: `Version 13.1 (13A1030d)` ; MacOS: `Big Sur 11.5.2`

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me fix the problem [the link](https://milanpanchal24.medium.com/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios-file-for-8c0cc28ec832)

#### What I did ?

At the end of my Podfile i add the following snippet and i run `pod install` command through terminal.

```js
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "YES"
    end
  end
end
```